# hortonworks : start datanode failed

Tags: hadoop

I have installed a new cluster HDP 2.3 using ambari 2.2. the problem is that namenode service can't be started and each time I try, I get the folowwing error. when I tried to find the problem I found an other error more explicit (port 50070 is used and I think that namenode use this port). Any one Has solved this problem before? thanks

> resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh
>   su hdfs -l -s /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -c unlimited ; 
>   /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config
>   /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf start namenode'' returned 1.
>   starting namenode, logging to
>   /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-ip-10-8-23-175.eu-west-2.compute.internal.out

Answer (score 0):

in order to install hortonworks cluster, ambari tries to set core file size limit to unlimited if not set initially. It seems like linux user which is installing the cluster doesn't have the privileges to set ulimits. 
just set core file size to unlimited in
 **/etc/security/limits.conf** and it should come up.

```
*               soft    core            unlimited
*               hard    core            unlimited
```